# Задача 1 Укус Питона

Tags: python-3.x

[image: код программы]
Код слизан с книги, с локальными исправлениями архиватора, шаги программы понял, первая задача из Укус Питона, вопрос в том, как исправить кодировку, чтобы кириллица отображалась корректно? Спасибо. И на сколько это вообще необходимо. [image: проблема]

Comment: Переведите исходный код и кодировку консоли в UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ приходит верно, в Unicode. Если очень надо можно сконвертировать в UTF8.
Python и UTF8
https://habrahabr.ru/post/135913/
В python3 все str по умолчанию в Unicode